# Extracting a function using ida pro

Tags: windows, reverse-engineering, ida

I've been reverse engineering a dll i believe to contain malicious code using IDA pro, and I've identified a very important subroutine.
In order to facilitate unit testing, i'd like to reimplement the subroutine in my own application, but re-writing the entire codebase has proven both tedious and prone to error. 
I've already identified and re-written the types involved in the subroutine, and was wondering if there was a way I could quickly extract the subroutine in native code and copy-paste it into my application.

Answer (score 0):

This "might" help you out? http://www.idabook.com/x86emu/

Why can't you just copy paste the instructions into a C program and run through the logic that way? There is probably even a python stub for this already.